# How to enter time on Symfony2 form in 12-hour format?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to create a Symfony2 form where I need to enter a date and time for the beginning of an event, which is saved as a property in DateTime format. Currently, the time is entered using a dropdown box in 24-hour format. I'm trying to change it to a 12-hour format. According to [this post](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6587), Symfony TimeType does not support a 12-hour format. One way of getting around this problem is to use a JQuery plugin for entering time, but I'm trying to avoid this. The easiest way to do it is shown in a comment by jarofgreen in the [post](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6587) linked above, where he proposes a small patch for the Symfony vendor code in TimeType.php. I tried implementing this change and it works great. The problem is that I need to do this without changing the vendor code. Instead, I decided to create an extension for TimeType, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443989/symfony-2-1-how-can-i-display-a-single-text-time-field-in-12-hour-am-pm-format).

I copied the TimeType.php from vendor code in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TimeType.php`, made the required changes to it, and saved it as MyTimeType under `src/AppBundle/Form/Type`. The problem is that the property I'm trying to change belongs to DateTimeType format, not TimeType. As far as I understand, the DateTimeType uses DateType and TimeType to create a DateTime object. My question is, what changes do I need to make to DateTimeType, so that it will use MyTimeType instead of TimeType to create a DateTime object?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) library. It creates a 12-hour dropdown menu for entering time and saves the time in 24-hour format. The only problem with this approach has to do with timezones. In our application, the start time for an event is entered in a form together with a local timezone. The time is saved in a database in UTC format and the timezone is saved in a separate field. Prior to using the datetimepicker library, the time was entered using the 24-hour dropdown menu and was saved correctly, taking the local timezone into account. After adding the datetimepicker, the time is not converted to UTC correctly when the local timezone is not the same as the system timezone specified in php.ini. We decided to not spend much more time on this and ended up removing the variable timezone field.  That's not the optimal solution, but in this case it was much more important to be able to enter time in 12-hour format than to be able to enter variable timezones.